# Onlick on SVG icon can be path or svg, how to make only SVG?

Tags: javascript, css

I have SVG icon that fire event if clicked. Problem is that onClick event target can be not only SVG, but path, if i click on path inside svg. Is there a way to make path and svg as whole?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's was simplier that i thought. You can just add  `pointer-events: 'none'` to every path inside svg.